# Data source name too long error in excel vba

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to Oracle sql developer by using excel vba. I have written the connection string in a way to avoid `tnsname.ora` issue. But now, I am  getting `Data source too long` error. I was trying to solve this for the past one week, but still not able to find a way out. Please help me. My code is below.

```
             Dim strCon
             Dim oCon
             DIM oRs
             strCon= "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=                                 (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=x0319vt110)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DD815)));
             User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
             Set oCon=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
             Set oRs=CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
             oCon.Open strCon
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the [Server specifier](http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/omiting-tnsnamesora/) rather than the Data Source.

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
```